# Does the notion of "boundary" need a metric?

Tags: general-topology

Every time I think of the notion of the "boundary" of a set, I think of a topology induced by some metric (typically the Euclidean metric). This, so far it seems, gives a concise definition of what the "boundary" of a set is.

**However, is there a more general definition of the boundary of a set that doesn't rely on a metric?**

Please excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a metric to talk about the boundary of a set, you only need a topology. Let $X$ be a topological space, and let $U\subset X$. Then $x\in X$ is a boundary point of $U$ is every neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $U$ and $X\setminus U$ non-trivially.

Comment: What does neighborhood mean?

Comment: A neighborhood of $x$ is any open set that contains $x$.

Answer (score 2):

For any topological space $X$ and any subset $A$, the **boundary** of $A$ is the topological subspace
$$\partial A := \overline{A} \cap \overline{X - A},$$
where $\overline{B}$ denotes the closure of $B$ in the topology on $X$. In particular, this notion depends only on the topology on $X$, and in particular does not require a metric.